# Как обратиться к элементу списка по индексу в шаблонизаторе Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, шаблонизаторы

Передаю во view в контекстном меню список элементов. Нужно работать с элементами этого списка во фронтенде, использовать их в js-e. Как вывести все элементы из списка -- очевидно (`{% for ... %}`), однако как работать с каждым из этих элементов в js скрипте? Как получить элементы списка? (По типу {{list_name[0]}} или {{list_name[1]}})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Django обращение к элементу списка происходит так, будто это данные из объекта, т.е.:

```py
# views.py
def someview(request, page):
    return render(request, 'articles/page.html', {'data': (request.user, page)})
```

```html
{# шаблон #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Статьи. Страница {{data.1}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Вы вошли как {{data.0.first_name}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Именно как `{{data.1}}` происходит обращение к данным (что в python эквивалентно `data[1]`)

Comment: а есть ли возможность в качестве индекса использовать переменную внутри js скрипта?

Comment: Дело в том, что JS работает на стороне клиента, в то время как шаблоны Django работают непосредственно на сервере. Пользователь не получает никаких шаблонов. Django по шаблону генерирует страницу и уже готовую страницу отправляет пользователю. Со стороны клиента работать с шаблонами уже нельзя.